# sass set width as variable if its not known

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm using SASS in my project and I want to set variable which is equal to `0.1*width` of content element. But this width in sass is not declare, I mean this width is set in js as `(window).height * x` (it just example), so in CSS file there is no declaration of `content{width: x;}`

to be more specyfic i have one content, which have width and height generated in js but other things in sass:

```
.content{background:red; padding:10px;}
```

and I want to create variable which is 10% of width of .content, and variable which is 12% of height of this element to make flexible layout in it (I want to make something like grid on this `.content`), and as you can see there is no declaration of this elements in SASS I mean width and height.

Is there a possibility to create this variables (`$widthCell = .content.width`) ?

Comment: SASS doesn't work like that, it's still as "smart" as CSS.

Comment: so Sass only know variables which are declared?

Comment: your SASS code is getting compiled in to regular CSS, it doesn't know anything about the actual DOM.